# Laravel5 Installation Issue (LINUX MINT 17.1 Cinnamon)

Tags: php, linux, laravel-5

I have been trying to install Laravel5 using Composer (on my Xampp server). I have followed all the steps from the official Laravel's site, but I am getting the following errors while installing the dependencies.

> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for laravel/framework v5.0.16 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.0.16]. 
>  
>       - laravel/framework v5.0.16 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.

I have even installed php5 mcrypt but still having the same issue. I have followed so many forums (including Stack Overflow) but none of the answers worked for me.

Comment: What version in Php. Did you enable mcrypt using php5enmod mcrypt or is the module active when checking the phpinfo?

Comment: I installed php5 mcrypt using sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt

Comment: no its not enabled, could you please guide me how to do that?

Comment: I have just enabled it, but still having the same issue

Comment: is the module enabled for cli as well? The test is performed on the cli version (/etc/php5/cli/conf.d -> mcrypt.ini)

Comment: did you use this  command "sudo php5enmod mcrypt" ?